# Power Automate Flow from Outlook Calendar to SharePoint List (When event is added, updated, or deleted)

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, power-automate

I have successfully created a flow that will add an event but when an event is modified it creates a duplicate.  I am having trouble with the different actions and logical conditions.  What specific identifier links Outlook Event to SharePoint List entry?

[image: My current flow]

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two issues going on here:
First, you might not need to use a Get Events action.  When this flow is triggered, it will automatically have a lot of information about the event that was created, updated, or deleted.  The iCalUId field makes sense to use, and you will definitely get that for the single event that is triggering this flow.

Second, if you simply use that triggering event to add a new item to SharePoint, there will not necessarily be anything linking the original Outlook event to the SharePoint list item.  You need to set something up yourself to do that.  The simplest way would be to make a column in your SharePoint list called Outlook iCalUId (make it a single-line text column in SharePoint).  Then, when you create a new SharePoint list item, use the iCalUId field from the outlook event to populate that field in the SharePoint list.

One trick you may run into is that you will need to determine right away if the triggering event is new, has been updated, or has been deleted.  You can use the trigger's Action Type field for that.  If it were me, I would use some sort of condition step or switch step to choose which actions come next: Create a SharePoint List Item/Update SharePoint List Item/Remove SharePoint List Item.